# Why wasn't this json property name the same when originally copied and when erased and written again?

Tags: json, text, unicode

I needed to process this JSON in C#, but even after creating a helper class to which I serialized the json-object using Newtonsoft's [JsonProperty("First name")] tag for the class properties, the json was not serialized correctly. Specifically, the C#-object had null values in its FirstName and LastName properties after serialization.

```
{   
   "attributes":{
          "First name":"John",
          "Last name":"Doe"
    }
}
```

**However, this is not a question on Newtonsoft or C#, because those weren't the problem**; Originally, I had just copied the json from a colleague in Teams, and then pasted it as the input to my function, and the error persisted. Then I thought (for no apparent reason) to erase the property names in the copied json and write them again, exactly like they were, and the serialization started working fine.

In the code snippet is the original json copied from Teams (with the values changed and irrelevant properties removed). I don't know how it could matter but I think the colleague uses macOS (where the line endings (which I have no knowledge of) are different).

**My question is:** how was this possible and what information is carried over when copying and pasting text around?

Answer (score 1):

The code string displayed in your question is not valid JSON, although it would be allowed in JavaScript. There is an unexpected comma character at the end of the second object member. It should be:

```
{   
   "attributes":{
          "First name":"John",
          "Last name":"Doe"
    }
}
```

You can make use of the online [JSON Validator](https://jsonlint.com/) to catch this error by yourself.

JSON syntax is quite strict, as described in the official page: [Introducing JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). In an object (or an array), commas are *separators*, not *terminators*.

Comment: My bad, that's actually just an artefact of removing the properties that followed for the sake of clarity for this post. The original JSON used was valid (I wrote that it serialized correctly after rewriting the property names). I removed the extra comma from my post.